# How to read and process CSV files without MS Office installed

Tags: c#, excel, csv, ms-office

I have a requirement where in I need to remove dependency of MS Office to read and work on CSV files since the client does not want to have MS Office installed on the server. I was trying EPPlus but it seems it does not work correctly with .CSV files.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of CSV parsers/readers available for C#, a quick google for "C# CSV parser" turns up several libraries and a few SO questions on the same topic.

Comment: Since when do programs require that **Office be installed** in order to parse **CSV**?

Comment: A CSV is just a text file. What are you doing to the file that makes you think you need office installed?

Comment: ApplicationClass m_App = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

m_Book = m_App.Workbooks.Open(m_strExcelBook,
                    m_Missing, m_Missing, m_Missing, m_Missing,
                    m_Missing, m_Missing, m_Missing, m_Missing,
                    m_Missing, m_Missing, m_Missing, m_Missing);

m_Book = m_App.Workbooks.Open(m_strExcelBook,
                    m_Missing, true, m_Missing, m_Missing,
                    m_Missing, m_Missing, m_Missing, m_Missing,
                    m_Missing, m_Missing, m_Missing, m_Missing);

m_SwapDataSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)m_Book.Worksheets[REPORTINDEX];

Comment: ApplicationClass m_App = new Excel.ApplicationClass(); 
This is where I am getting error ; I am unsure how to change it to work without MS office

Answer (score 0):

**Very easy solution that I used too:**

Download DLL and more detailed information [From here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)

```
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), true))
    {
        int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;    
        string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
        while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0} = {1};",
                              headers[i], csv[i]));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```